# Sequence of alternating heads and tails

Tags: python

I am working on this challenge:

> There are N coins, each showing either heads or tails. We would like all the coins to form a sequence of alternating heads and tails. What is the minimum number of coins that must be reversed to achieve this?
>
> Write a function:
>
> ```
> def solution (A)
> ```
>
> ...that, given an array A consisting of N integers representing the coins, returns the minimum number of coins that must be reversed.
> Consecutive elements of array A represent consecutive coins and contain either a 0 (heads) or a 1 (tails).
>
> #### Examples:
>
> 1. Given array `A = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]`, the function should return  1. After reversing the sixth coin, we achieve an alternating sequence of coins:
>
>    ```
>    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0].
>    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0].
>    ```
> 2. Given array `A = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]`, the function should return 2. After reversing the first and fifth coins, we achieve an alternating sequence.
> 3. Given array `A = [0, 1, 0]`, the function should return 0. The sequence of coins is already alternating.
> 4. Given array `A = [0, 1, 1, 0]`, the function should return 2. We can reverse the first and second coins to get the sequence: `[1, 0, 1, 0]`.
>
> Assume that:
>
> - N is an integer within the range [1..100];
> - each element of array A is an integer that can have one of the following values: 0, 1.
>
> In your solution, focus on correctness. The performance of your solution will not be the focus of the assessment.

#### My function

```py
def solution(A):
    # Initialize a variable to count the number of reversals needed.
    reversals_needed = 0
    
    # Iterate through the array starting from the second coin (index 1).
    for i in range(1, len(A)):
        # Check if the current coin has the same value as the previous one.
        if A[i] == A[i - 1]:
            # If they are the same, increment the reversals_needed by 1.
            reversals_needed += 1
    
    # Return the total number of reversals needed.
    return reversals_needed
```

I called the function as follows:

```py
print(solution([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]))  # Expected output: 1
print(solution([1, 1, 0, 1, 1]))     # Expected output: 2
print(solution([0, 1, 0]))           # Expected output: 0
print(solution([0, 1, 1, 0]))        # Expected output: 2
```

### Problem

When input is: `[0, 1, 1, 0]`, then my code returns 1, where it should return 2.

What is my mistake?

Comment: I guess you want to count a reversal when the current and previous coins differ, no? Not when they are the same.

Comment: Instead of pasting your assignment here, you should distill it down to only the information that is relevant to your question. Did you try any debugging to figure out why your function returns the wrong answer? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not find the bug for you here; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you count one reversal, then in the next iteration you should be aware that `A[i-1]` was supposed to be reversed. But as you don't have that logic, you're getting the wrong conclusion in this next iteration.

Another way to look at this, is to not rely on the previous list value, but to rely only on the index. If the index is odd, aim for the coin to be 1, and if the index is even, aim for the coin to be 0.

At the end you can choose out of two scenarios. Either you go with the count you got, or you aim for the complete inverse (1 <-> 0), i.e. where all **except** the counted coins are reversed. Take the minimum of both.

Implementation:

```
def solution(A):
    reversals_needed = 0
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i] == i % 2:
            reversals_needed += 1
    return min(reversals_needed, len(A) - reversals_needed)
```

Comment: but @trincot how did you get this answer quickly, I mean how you got this  idea/approach quickly.

Comment: I guess it is decades of experience that builds a certain intuition, so that the right idea bubbles up. But it doesn't always happen like that when I want it to though :P

Comment: Just a variation: `reversals_needed = A[0::2].count(0) + A[1::2].count(1)`

Comment: Nice use if `count`, @Kelly!

Answer (score 0):

Your code calculates the number of reversals without considering the previous reversals that may or may not have been necessary. When your code reaches index 3 in the list `[0, 1, 1, 0]`, it doesn't take into account that it had to reverse the number before it at index 2, and all it sees is that 0 is not equal to 1. Fixing this is as easy as mutating the list whenever a reversal is done.

However, this would also create another bug which would make the second test return 3. The fact that your original code returned 2 anyways was just a coincidence, but starting at index 1 means that it is forced to get to `[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]` using 3 flips instead of `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]` using 2 flips. To fix this you should start at index 0, and change your condition so that you don't get an index out of bounds error. What I mean by this is you can keep your current condition, but make it only run when `i > 0` and add a second condition for when `i == 0`.

Comment: How would you handle `i == 0`?

Comment: `if (i > 0 and A[i] == A[i - 1]) or (i == 0 and A[i] == A[i + 1])`

Comment: i would still recommend trincot's response tho

Comment: I don't think that suffices. Would you mind posting the whole function so we can try it?